# Get data from multidimensional array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array like this:

```
   {#184 ▼
      +"Column_name1": "value1"
      +"Column_name2": "value2"
      +"Column_name3": "value3"
      +"Column_name4": "value4"
      +"Column_name5": "value5"
      +"Column_name1": "value6"
    }
#187
    ...
```

I have got the array from MsSQL using a raw query with procedure

I want to get an array with the DB columns names

I expect something like this:

```
['Column_name1','Column_name2'...]
```

How could I split the array?

Comment: You shouldn't work on arrays in Laravel... work in Collections and then on collection use pluck('field')->toArray(); for example: User::all()->pluck('email')->toArray();

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods provided by php.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);
```

$keys and $values will both be arrays